# JSON Использование

Tags: c#

Подскажите как возможно получить и записать значения json в файле

```
if(!File.Exists(ArizonaConfig))
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> points = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "name", "1.7.1" },
                { "lastVersionId", "1.7.10" },
                { "playerUUID", "******" },
                { "launcherVisibilityOnGameClose", "keep the launcher open" },
            };
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(points, Formatting.Indented);
            File.WriteAllText(ArizonaConfig, json, Encoding.Default);;
        }
```

Comment: Ну, а чем вас ваш код не устраивает?

Comment: @VladD Да я хз теперь как получить например значение из файла например playerUUID - points - всего 1 раз создается - после перезапуска пропадает

Comment: Ээээ... А как это файл пропадает? Чудес не бывает, ищите в коде, где вы его удаляете.

Comment: @VladD где я сказал,что файл пропадает?Я сказал что Dictionary только 1 раз создается если нету файла - если есть нужно чтобы он загружался из него

Comment: Ваш вопрос, цитирую, «как возможно получить и записать значения json». Ваш код именно это и делает: записывает JSON. Может быть, вам нужно не записать, а прочитать?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var item in dictName) // заменить dictName на название вашего словаря
{
    if(dictName.Key == "name")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("User name is - " + dictName.Value);
    }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```